# How to use tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage in keras model in tensorflow2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification

I'm building a deep learning model to do some classification, but I fount if I use random cropping, the validation accuracy fluctuate a lot. I want to use the running average of the training model of a short window to help validation accuracy, but I'm really confused about the use of it. I'm using keras's inceptionv3 model.

I'm using keras's inceptionv3 model and want to use the running average of the training model of a short window to help validation accuracy.

```
ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.99, step)
maintain_average = ema.apply()


model = tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3(include_top=True, weights=None, input_tensor=None, input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=4)

def step_decay(epoch):
    initial_lrate = 0.045
    drop = 0.9
    epochs_drop = 2.0
    lrate = initial_lrate * math.pow(drop,  
           math.floor((epoch)/epochs_drop))
    return lrate

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.02, momentum=0.9, epsilon=0.1),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpoint_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("classification_model_tf2.0_test.h5",                                          
                                                   save_best_only=True)
early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10,                                  
                                                  restore_best_weights=True)

lrate = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)

history = model.fit_generator(
    data_generator(train_dataset),
    steps_per_epoch=train_steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[lrate, checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb],
    validation_data=data_generator(validation_dataset),
    validation_steps=vali_steps_per_epoch,
    workers = 0  # runs generator on the main thread
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can use tfa.optimizers.MovingAverage instead tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage
https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/MovingAverage

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa


opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.02, momentum=0.9, epsilon=0.1)
opt = tfa.optimizers.MovingAverage(opt)
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.